# How can I assign a DBNull in a better way?

Tags: c#, .net, parsing, datarow, dbnull

I need to parse a value from a `DataRow` and assign it to another `DataRow`. If the input is valid, then I need to parse it to a `double`, or else add a `DBNull` value to the output. I'm using the following code:

```
public double? GetVolume(object data)
{
    string colValue = data == null ? string.Empty : data.ToString();
    double volume;

    if (!Double.TryParse(colValue.ToString(), out volume))
    {
        return null;
    }
    return volume;
}

public void Assign(DataRow theRowInput,DataRow theRowOutput)
{
    double? volume = GetVolume(theRowInput[0]);

    if(volumne.HasValue)
    theRowOutput[0] = volume.value;
    else
    theRowOutput[0] = DbNull.Value;

    return theRowOutput;
}
```

Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

How about:

```
    public double? GetVolume(object data)
    {
        double value;
        if (data != null && double.TryParse(data.ToString(), out value))
            return value;
        return null;
    }

    public void Assign(DataRow theRowInput, DataRow theRowOutput)
    {
        theRowOutput[0] = (object)GetVolume(theRowInput[0]) ?? DBNull.Value;
    }
```

Comment: @Adeel we are assigning to a `DataRow` cell by indexer, which *inherently* involves boxing...

Answer (score 0):

What about something simple like this:

```
double dbl;
if (double.TryParse(theRowInput[0] as string, out dbl))
    theRowOutput[0] = dbl;
else
    theRowOutput[0] = DbNull.Value;
```

**EDIT:** This code assumes the input is of type string. You weren't 100% clear there. If it was another type, the code above would need to be tweaked slightly.

Comment: the `as string` isn't quite the same - the original cell could be an `int`, for example. In reality, `Convert.ToDouble` may be a better choice overall...

Comment: @Marc Where did you get the original cell could be `int`?

Comment: Purely looking at the code, which knows nothing about the source other than `object`....

Comment: @Marc He's reading it from a database. I assumed he knew the type. I guess he wasn't explicit.

Answer (score 0):

Here are my two messy cents:

```
decimal dParse;
if ((cells[13] == "" ? LP_Eur = DBNull.Value : (Decimal.TryParse(cells[13], NumberStyles.Number, NumberFormat, out dParse) ? LP_Eur = dParse : LP_Eur = null)) != null) {
    throw new Exception("Ivalid format");
}
```